# Error updating initialNavigation during ng update

Tags: angular, npm

I am currently updating an angular app from 10.2 to 17.0 following the https://update.angular.io guide

I had to downgrade my current node version to even get the first command to run correctly :
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11

When running the command the package.json is updated correctly, however as we go along I am hitting the following error :

```
▸ Updates the `initialNavigation` property for `RouterModule.forRoot`.
✖ Migration failed: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
See "/tmp/ng-5dA4uE/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The log file contains the following information :

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.getImportOfIdentifier (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/utils/typescript/imports.js:24:45)
    at Object.isExtraOptions (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/util.js:37:31)
    at InitialNavigationCollector.getLiteralNeedingMigration (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:96:24)
    at InitialNavigationCollector.visitNode (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:48:44)
    at /....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:55:49
    at visitNodes (/....projectpath/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31214:30)
    at forEachChildInVariableDeclarationList (/....projectpath/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31582:20)
    at Object.forEachChild (/....projectpath/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31988:47)
    at InitialNavigationCollector.visitNode (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:55:20)
    at /....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:55:49
```

The only place RouterModule.forRoot is referred to in the project is in the App routing module :

```
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Where routes is not undefined

Has anyone solved this issue before?
Thanks

I am currently updating an angular app from 10.2 to 17.0 following the https://update.angular.io guide

I had to downgrade my current node version to even get the first command to run correctly :
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11

When running the command the package.json is updated correctly, however as we go along I am hitting the following error :

```
▸ Updates the `initialNavigation` property for `RouterModule.forRoot`.
✖ Migration failed: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
See "/tmp/ng-5dA4uE/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The log file contains the following information :

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.getImportOfIdentifier (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/utils/typescript/imports.js:24:45)
    at Object.isExtraOptions (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/util.js:37:31)
    at InitialNavigationCollector.getLiteralNeedingMigration (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:96:24)
    at InitialNavigationCollector.visitNode (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:48:44)
    at /....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:55:49
    at visitNodes (/....projectpath/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31214:30)
    at forEachChildInVariableDeclarationList (/....projectpath/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31582:20)
    at Object.forEachChild (/....projectpath/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31988:47)
    at InitialNavigationCollector.visitNode (/....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:55:20)
    at /....projectpath/node_modules/@angular/core/schematics/migrations/initial-navigation/collector.js:55:49
```

The only place RouterModule.forRoot is referred to in the project is in the App routing module :

```
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Where routes is not undefined

Has anyone solved this issue before?
Thanks